# This is sufficient to prove by induction that 2n < n! for n >= 4?

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I start with base saying that this is valid for one by simple algebraic calculus:

This is my base for $ n = 4$
$$ 2 \cdot 4  \leq 4! \Leftrightarrow 8 \leq 24  $$

In my hypotheses just say that exists a number $k$ that satisfies the expression for some $k\geq 4$:
$$ 2k < k! $$

And my inductive step I multiply both sides from hypotheses by $(k+1)$ as follows:
$$ (k+1) \cdot 2k < k! \cdot (k+1) $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow (k+1) \cdot 2k < (k+1)! $$

So by hypotheses we know that $k\geq 4$ soon can afirms that $2k(k+1) > 2k$. Given that $(k+1)! > 2k(k+1)$ and $2k(k+1) > 2k$ is proved by induction that $2n < n!$

> I wrong anything or is insufficient to prove the enunciated?

Comment: In the inductive step you have toshow that $2(k+1) < (k+1)!$

Comment: You need to add an additional step $(k+1)\cdot2k>(k+1)\cdot2$ which is pretty obvious.

Comment: Seems hard to build an inductive proof that avoids the simplification $2n<n!\Leftarrow 2<(n-1)!$, a non-inductive proof.

Comment: "soon can afirms that 2k(k+1)>2k"  You don't want to affire $2k(k+1) > 2k$.  You want to affirm $2k(k+1) > 2(k+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often better to prove it in one line:

$2(k+1) = 2k + 2 < k!+2 < k!\cdot (k+1) = (k+1)!$,

where the first inequality is by induction hypothesis and the second inequality holds for $k\geq 4$ anyway (for completeness, it could also be proved by induction).

Answer (score 2):

Fixe that $2k(k+1) > 2(k+1)$ and not $2k(k+1) > 2k$ and your proof is fine.

Alternatively it might be simpler to go left to right rather than right to left

$2k < k!$

$2k + 2 < k! + 2 < k! + 2\cdot 3 < k! + 2\cdot 3\cdot 4 < ...... < k! + k! =$

$2k! < (k+1)k! = (k+1)!$.

....

You know.... as far as inequalities go... this aint even close.

Comment: Yes this was my second attempt, first I tried get out from $2(k+1) < (k+1)!$ to $2k < k!$ but I spended a lot time and move to on with this attempt from right to left

Comment: It's always better to go from what you know ($2k < k!$) to what you want to prove ($2(k+1) < (k+1)!$) rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

**A simpler proof:**

For all naturals, $$2<(n-1)!\implies 2n< n!$$
and it suffices to prove

$$n\ge3\implies n!>2.$$

Very easily,

$$3!>2$$ and

$$n!>2\implies (n+1)n!>2.$$

Comment: `We silently used the property 1≤n!.` you use this on green hightlight right?

Comment: @pic: not at all, this is from inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Ok, now I see, but the last inequality shouldn't be a $n!+n \leq n!+n!n$ given that $n!$ on $n!n$ can be one ?

Comment: @pic: I have completely changed my answer.